# BASE jumping from One World Trade Center

Tags: cipher

The well-known daredevil, Sauren Baumgartner, is standing on the top of One World Trade Center (in Lower Manhattan) just before sunset. Following his physical and mental preparation, he calmly drops over the edge of the building. During his BASE jumping descent, he spirals four times before landing safely on the ground.

Find out where Sauren landed by decoding this cipher:

```
065 063 040 065 063 040 063 062 040 065 062 040 065 066 040 063 062 040 065 063 040 065 064 040 063 062 040 065 065 040 065 062 040 063 062 040 065 064 040 065 061 040 063 062 040 065 062 040 065 065 040 063 062 040 065 064 040 065 066 040 063 062 040 065 065 040 065 064 040 063 062 040 065 064 040 065 062 040 063 062 040 065 063 040 065 066 040 063 062 040 065 062 040 061 060 061 040 063 062 040 065 064 040 071 071 040 063 062 040 065 062 040 071 067 040 063 062 040 065 063 040 065 062 040 063 062 040 065 062 040 065 067 040 063 062 040 065 065 040 065 065 040 063 062 040 065 063 040 065 063 040 063 062 040 065 062 040 065 065 040 063 062 040 065 062 040 065 064 040 063 062 040 065 065 040 065 067 040 063 062 040 065 064 040 064 071 040 063 062 040 065 065 040 065 065 040 063 062 040 065 061 040 061 060 060 040 063 062 040 065 061 040 061 060 060
```

<sub>**(The answer is two words)**</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is:

> Pumphouse Park

Which is obtained by:

> Converting from octal to text which yields:
> 53 53 32 52 56 32 53 54 32 55 52 32 54 51 32 52 55 32 54 56 32 55 54 32 54 52 32 53 56 32 52 101 32 54 99 32 52 97 32 53 52 32 52 57 32 55 55 32 53 53 32 52 55 32 52 54 32 55 57 32 54 49 32 55 55 32 51 100 32 51 100
> Then converting from decimal to text which yields:
> 55 48 56 74 63 47 68 76 64 58 4e 6c 4a 54 49 77 55 47 46 79 61 77 3d 3d
> Then converting from hex to text which yields:
> UHVtcGhvdXNlJTIwUGFyaw==
> Then converting from BASE64 to text which yields:
> Pumphouse%20Park
> Which then URL decodes to 'Pumphouse Park'

Answer (score 4):

Convert from octal to ASCII:

53 53 32 52 56 ...

Then convert from decimal to ASCII:

55 48 56 74 ...

Then once more from decimal to ASCII:

708J...

I'm on my phone right now, but I'll fill in the rest once I have access to a proper keyboard.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I wasn't able to look at all the text properly, and therefore somebody got to it before I did. ;-)